# Does closeness in trace distance imply close measurement outcomes?

Tags: density-matrix, povm, linear-algebra

Suppose we have two density matrices $\rho$ and $\rho'$ such that $\|\rho - \rho'\|_1 \leq \varepsilon$. Let $\{\Lambda, I - \Lambda\}$ be elements of some POVM. If it holds that

$$Tr(\Lambda\rho) \leq \delta$$

then is it also true that

$$Tr(\Lambda\rho')$$

can be upper bounded in terms of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can bound $\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda\rho')$ in terms of $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$ as follows
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda\rho')&=\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda\rho)+\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda(\rho'-\rho))\tag1\\
&\le\delta+\mathrm{tr}(\Lambda(\rho'-\rho))\tag2\\
&\le\delta+D(\rho,\rho')\tag3\\
&=\delta+\frac12\|\rho-\rho'\|_1\tag4\\
&\le\delta+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
where $D(\rho,\sigma):=\frac12\|\rho-\sigma\|_1$ is the trace distance between $\rho$ and $\sigma$. Inequality $(3)$ follows from the fact that
$$
D(\rho,\sigma)=\max_E\mathrm{tr}\left(E(\rho-\sigma)\right)\tag6
$$
where the maximization is done over all positive operators $E\le I$. For a proof of $(6)$ see the text following equation $(9.22)$ on page $404$ in Nielsen & Chuang. It is an application of Jordan-Hahn decomposition.

Comment: Thank you, that's a neat trick with (6)!